# Netbeans 8.0 and phonegap - build process too slow

Tags: html, cordova, netbeans, cordova-3

I really like Netbeans 8.0 and it supports (officially) Cordova.

Unfortunately, For me Building an application takes more than 1'30'' (in this last case total time: 1 minute 42 seconds)
which is too much on basic application (I just have 4 core plugins in it) and with Eclipse the same application builds much faster.

**

- **Is there anything I can do to increase my build speed?**

**

I cannot post all the log because it is too big for SO but there are many things are reapeted a number of times, for instance these lines:

1. skipping existing file: index.md
2. cp: dest file already exists: C:\Users\user1\Documents\NetBeansProjects\myapp\plugins\org.apache.cordova.device\CONTRIBUTING.md
   cp: dest file already exists: C:\Users\user1\Documents\NetBeansProjects\myapp\plugins\org.apache.cordova.device\LICENSE
3. cp: dest file already exists: C:\Users\user1\Documents\NetBeansProjects\myapp\plugins\org.apache.cordova.splashscreen\CONTRIBUTING.md
   cp: dest file already exists: C:\Users\user1\Documents\NetBeansProjects\myapp\plugins\org.apache.cordova.splashscreen\LICENSE
   cp: dest file already exists: C:\Users\user1\Documents\NetBeansProjects\myapp\plugins\org.apache.cordova.splashscreen\NOTICE
   cp: dest file already exists: C:\Users\user1\Documents\NetBeansProjects\myapp\plugins\org.apache.cordova.splashscreen\plugin.xml
   cp: dest file already exists: C:\Users\user1\Documents\NetBeansProjects\myapp\plugins\org.apache.cordova.splashscreen\README.md
   cp: dest file already exists: C:\Users\user1\Documents\NetBeansProjects\myapp\plugins\org.apache.cordova.splashscreen\RELEASENOTES.md

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Netbeans build process for Cordova/PhoneGap is very slow for me also (HelloWorld takes over a minute and a half to build) and if you 'Run' it again even without modifications it builds the whole thing again!

I don't know how to speed up the build process for a particular platform but if you switch to 'Embedded WebKit Browser' and then run your app, it is very quick as you skip the entire build process.

So for now, I would recommend developing using the integrated (or external) browser and then doing a build to iOS/Android when you reach certain milestones.

Hope this helps.